# How can I access functions defined in Google Script Editor outside of it?

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

If I have a function written in Google Spreadsheets script editor that retrieves the data in the spreadsheet in JSON format, how can I access that function outside of the script editor in my own code? I want to access that JSON and manipulate it in my own code. Is there a way to do that using the Spreadsheets API? I format it in a specific way inside script editor so I can't just use the json-in-script provided. In the call (http://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/feed/key/worksheet/public/basic?alt=json-in-script&callback=myFunc) there's a callback function for myFunc. Can I use the function I defined in the script editor to replace myFunc?

Comment: what do you mean by "outside of the script editor" ? in another SS ? in another app ? please clarify.

Comment: @Sergeinsas in another application. In this case, it is a web application. How would I be able to call on the function defined in the script editor in the code for this web application?

Answer (score 1):

Following your comment that brings some details on your use case, there is a Google-Apps-Script feature specially designed to give access to some functions you wrote from within another script : is is called **libraries** and is fully [described in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries).

---

**EDIT**, following 2cond comment:

Calling a GS function from a javascript (or any other language) script that is not a Google Script (GS) is not possible if you consider using it as a function...

### but

what you can eventually do - depending on the data this function must handle - is to deploy a script as a webApp running as a service and call this service from your external app using the equivalent of an [urlFetch](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/) (that's the service doing that in GS).

The service will have an url to which you can add parameters and it will return a result that you can use in your local app.

Of course this workflow has a few limitations and might quickly become complex but in many cases it is fully workable.

Note that the url you will have to use in the "versioned" one ending with .exec (Not sure this word is correct but I mean the published url that corresponds to a version of your script and not the ".dev" one that one can use to test a script in GS).

You'll find details about that in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/execution_web_apps) and on many other ressources, including SO. The url is typically something like this :

```
https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyw-2WtmF7wsd__________azjImbMWm5YrxB8/exec?someParameter=someValue&otherParam=otherVal // etc...
```

Comment: Thanks! So I see how one would be able to access a library and use the functions declared in said library in one's own Script Editor, but is it possible for one to access these library functions in a script that isn't written in Google Script Editor? 

For example, I have a Javascript file saved on my local host. I want to be able to pull the functions defined in said library into my own Javascript file. Is this possible? Or can library functions only be accessed across Google Script Editors?